# How to append ids of images to the list?

Tags: python, list, append

[Here is the image with a black border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCZMw.jpg)

I have a function to clear the black borders in the image. I would like to append the ids of the images which had black borders and whose shape is changed by the function. 
This is the black border removal function:

```py
def black_border_removal(image_path):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path,1)
    ind_row = []
    ind_col = []
    for row in range(image.shape[0]):
        if int(image[row, :].mean()) > 30:
            ind_row.append(row) # if the row intensity not black append

    img_new = image[ind_row, :] # Get only the rows that are not black

    for col in range(img_new.shape[1]):
        if int(img_new[:, col].mean()) > 30:
            ind_col.append(col) # if the column intensity not black append

    img_clear_border = img_new[:, ind_col] # Get only the columns that are not black
    list_cleared_border = []
    if image.shape != img_clear_border.shape:
        list_cleared_border.append(image_path)
    return(img_clear_border, list_cleared_border)
```

After that I used this code to store the image ids

```py
path_images = path/to/folder/of/images

for index, ids in enumerate(list_images):
    # index = range(0,len(list))
    # ids = names of the images
    border_removed, names = black_border_removal(path_images + str(ids))
```

When I do this the list `names` returns as an empty list. Why is that?

I also need to get the index of rows and cols removed. Because I will have to remove them from the ground truth images as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: List is empty if the images are the same size.  You need an [MCVE].

Comment: I added an image. You can try putting it in an empty folder and try to see if it appends on your machine and if it clears the border if you only use the function without the loop. On my machine it clears the border if I use the function without the loop, so it should append the image id but it does not. My first time trying to add an image, so I don't know how to make the image visible in the post but if you click on the link on the first line and download it.

Comment: Did read the link above?  You should take out all of the code in the question that is not directly related to the problem.

Comment: I believe all the code I shared is related to the question. Maybe I am not able to see which part is unneccesary, but if you think differently please explain. I am really new to the website.

Comment: The more code you force people to wade through, the less likely they are to do it.  Did you write that code?

Comment: I understand, but I couldn't think of a shorter way of clearing the border and yes I have written the code.

Comment: An [mcve] is not asking for a shorter way to clear the border.  It is asking for a shorter way to demonstrate the problem.